# Как сделать код без переменной shift?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть вот такая часть из React-Redux приложения:

```
onClick = event => {
    const shift = event.target.dataset.shift;
    this.setState(() => ({ shift }), this.filter);
  };
```

Хочу `event.target.dataset.shift` не ложить в переменную shift. Но как бы я не делал у меня ошибки. Вот как я переделал:

```
onClick = event => {

    this.setState(() => ({ shift: event.target.dataset.shift}), this.filter);
  };
```

И не работает(

Укажите пожалуйста на ошибку

Comment: а зачем нужно убрать эту переменную?

Comment: нужно чтобы в коде было меньше вложености

Comment: переменная не влияет на вложенность

Comment: @peterua Нужно писать код не короче, а понятнее и более читаемо. В дополнительной переменной нет ничего плохого, тем более когда ее область видимости ограничена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте деструктивное присваивание:

```
const onClick = ({ target: { dataset: { shift } } }) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ shift }), this.filter);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3q5u8ftm/

https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment